# Actions of compact Lie groups on (possibly but hopefully not) non-regular spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, group-actions, principal-bundles

Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group acting freely on a topological space $Q$ (about whose separation conditions I make no assumptions) and the qoutient $Q/G$ is known to be completely regular Hausdorff (or even paracompact Hausdorff). Can one deduce that $Q \to Q/G$ is a principal bundle? If $Q$ itself (rather than $Q/G$) were completely regular, this result is well known. Perhaps it follows that $Q$ must be completely regular if $Q/G$ is?

Comment: I guess the ending *not* in the parenthetical remark in your title is a typo?

Comment: Maybe you can use metrization theorem on the quotient and try to build a metric on $Q$ out of it and metric on $G$?

Comment: Think of the case when $G$ is finite and acts simply transitively.

Comment: Did you try to adapt Palais' proof of the slice theorem? MR0126506 (23 #A3802)  
Palais, Richard S.
On the existence of slices for actions of non-compact Lie groups. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 73 1961 295–323.

Comment: Maybe, you should add the requirement that each $G$-orbit (with subspace topology) is homeomorphic to $G$.

Answer (score 5):

Take $X$ to be finite with trivial topology, let $G$ be a finite cyclic group acting simply transitively on $X$. If you equip $G$ with discrete topology then it is a Lie group. The quotient $Y=X/G$ is a single point, so it satisfies all the regularity properties you can imagine. However, the quotient map $X\to Y$ is clearly not a bundle. Thus, at the very least you need the original space to be Hausdorff.